# WeldSE with JUnit5 - Can't inject dependencies

Tags: java-ee-8, weld-se, weld-junit5

This is my service class:

```
@Path("/foo")
@RequestScoped
public class FooService {

    @Inject @Log
    Logger logger;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String ping() {
        return "pong";
    }
}
```

In the same module I have an util class that provides the logger using a Log interface with *@Qualifier* annotation

```
public class WebResources {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }


    @Produces @Log
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a UnitTest using JUnit 5 + Weld SE

```
@EnableWeld
public class FooTest {

    @WeldSetup
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(FooService.class)
            .activate(RequestScoped.class)
            .build();


    @Test
    public void ping(FooService fooService) {

        fooService.ping();

    }

}
```

This produces the following error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Log
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Log it.infocert.shop.rest.FooService.logger
  at it.infocert.shop.rest.FooService.logger(FooService.java:0)
```

How can I add the @Log dependency to Weld SE properly in a unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that class `WebResources` isn't known to Weld once it starts the container for tests. The way it works is that you define what beans are in the container - you can add classes, packages and so on.

In your case, it should be enough to change the `WeldInitiator` creation like this:

```
@WeldSetup
public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(FooService.class, WebResources.class)
        .activate(RequestScoped.class)
        .build();
```

Note that there are various way how to start the `WeldInitiator` ranging from the simplest one such the one you use, all the way to providing your own fully configured `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld` object.